# Custom controls ribbon in TabComposeTools Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

i try to add custom control in the "reply inline" mode. I have no problem to add control in the "Compose tools" TabMessage control.

I try to set the IdMso of the tab to

```
TabMessage

TabNewMailMessage (this one work when i write a new email in a new popup)

TabComposeTools
```

It's dont work. Any suggestion ?

[image: Tab Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add custom controls to new Inspector compose window the following ribbon.xml will work. Please note this xml for new Inspector ...

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabNewMailMessage">
        <group id ="myGroupForInspector" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard"  getVisible="GetVisible"  getLabel="GetLabel">
        ... controls are go here
         </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

To add custom controls to Explorer inline compose window the following ribbon.xml will work. Please note this xml is for Explorer window ...

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <contextualTabs>
      <tabSet idMso="TabComposeTools">
        <tab idMso="TabMessage">
          <group id ="myGroupForExplorer" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard"  getVisible="GetVisible"  getLabel="GetLabel">
            ... controls are go here
          </group>
        </tab>
      </tabSet>
    </contextualTabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with the ribbon designer ?

Comment: As far as I know ribbon designer doesn't support this (Inline response).

Comment: @CédricBoivin This is small post on how to add it, if you have any concerns: [Outlook add-in: add ribbon to Message tab](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/865ee885-cc0b-4273-bd2c-257878065140?category=vsto)

Comment: Thanks. That is helpfull. An important point is Ribbon designer and ribbon xml could not be used at the same time, so if you are customizing ribbon using designer, I suggest you export it into xml.